# How do I obtain a list of the application domains my application has created?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, appdomain

I have a service app that creates AppDomain's during the course of its use for long running tasks. I've been tracking these by storing them in a Hashtable with a unique ID.

After a task is completed the service app then unloads the AppDomain allocated to that task and then it's removed it from the appdomain Hashtable.

Purely from a sanity checking point of view, is there a way I can query the CLR to see what app domains are still loaded by the creating app domain (i.e. so I can compare the tracking Hashtable against what the CLR actually sees)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you need to keep your own list - like you are already.

Comment: Yep...after a couple of months of off and on research. This does seem to be the way.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the unmanaged APIs you may set-up a DomainManager that gets called on each AppDomain creation, and you'll find that many pieces are creating their own AppDomains, e.g. WCF. A detailed explanatin is in [Customizing the Microsoft .NET Framework Common Language Runtime](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619883)

Another route is using the debug APIs.

Comment: Giulio - thanks for the answer and thanks for the link to the book. Can't believe I missed that one, looks fascinating.