# Message Pumps and AppDomains

Tags: c#, appdomain

I have a a C# (FFx 3.5) application that loads DLLs as plug-ins.  These plug-ins are loaded in separate AppDomains (for lots of good reasons, and this architecture cannot change).  This is all well and good.

I now have a requirement to show a Dialog from one of those plug-ins.  Bear in mind that I *cannot* return the dialog Form to the main application and have it displayed there (the current infrastructure doesn't support it).

Failure 1

In my DLL I created a Form and called Show.  The dialog outline showed up but did not paint and it doesn't respond to mouse events. I assumed that this is becasue the DLL is in a separate AppDomain and the message pump for the app is somehow unable to dispatch messages to the new Form.

Failure 2

In my DLL I created a Form and called ShowDialog, which by all rights should create an internal message pump for the dialog..  The dialog is displayed and responded to clicks (hooray), but it appears that the primary app no longer is processing or dispatching windows messages because it quits painting and no longer responds to mouse events.  For some reason now it seems that the main app's message pump is not dispatching.

Failure 3

In my DLL I created a Form and called Application.Run.  This will certainly create a complete second message pump.  I get the same behavior as Failure 2 - the Dialog behaves, but the calling app does not.

Any thoughts on what exactly is going on here and how I might go about showing a dialog from the other AppDomain's DLL and have both the caller and the callee still respond and paint properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using appdomain1's main form's BeginInvoke with a delegate that displays the form from appdomain2. So in Pseudocode:

```
Appdomain1:
    AppDomain2.DoSomething(myMainForm);

AppDomain2:
    DoSomething(Form parent)
    {
        Form foolishForm = new Form();
        parent.BeginInvoke(new Action( delegate { foolishForm.Show(); } ));
    }
```

The code may not be perfect, but it demonstrates the concept.

By the way, if you are having problems passing forms around because of remoting you can:

```
public class Container<T> : MarshalByRefObject
{
    private T _value;
    public T Value { get { return _value; } set { _value = value; } }

    public Container() { }
    public Container(T value) { Value = value; }

    public static implicit operator T(Container<T> container)
    {
        return container.Value;
    }
}
```

That will contain object you throw at it.

Comment: +1: Thanks for the suggestions. I like the concept of the container.  We may keep that in mind as we move forward.

Answer (score 1):

We have a very similarly architected application that loads DLL files and plugins. Each DLL file is loaded in a separate [application domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Domain), which is created on a separate thread. We have a third-party control in a form that would not appear unless we call `System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()` regularly.

Pseudo code:

```
<In new thread>
  <Application domain created. Start called inside new application domain.>
  <Start loads new DLL file, calls init function in DLL file>
  <Start loops, calling DoEvents until the DLL file exits>
  <Application domain unloaded>
<Thread exits>
```

This solved all of our GUI issues.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I've used before is implementing a [DomainManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainmanager.aspx). It's possible to customize the various [application domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Domain) security/binding/context's to handle complex or chicken-egg type problems with respect to pumping your data where you want ;)

I've ususally done this from a native.exe, bootstrapping the CLR through the COM interfaces (psudo code but the order and method names are correct ;):

```
CorBindToRuntimeEx()
SetHostControl()
GetCLRControl()
SetAppDomainManagerType("yourdomainmanger","info")
// Domain manager set before starting runtime
Start()
HostControl -- GetDomainManagerForDefaultDomain()
DomainManager -- Run()
```

Your domain manager can be any [CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) class library, so their's not that much more native C.

A side note, if you were in [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation); I really like using the "Microsoft.DwayneNeed.Controls" method. Where you may have disperate threads with their own Dispatcher pump in the *same* UI control (not needing to resort to entirely new Window()'s).

The unique thing about using this approach, is that even if the primary UI thread is blocked/busy (some heavy operation, scanning the filesystem, etc...), these other threads may paint/update their UIElement's without any hiccup.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/100864/giulio-vian answered another question with a link to a book which also document's how to do this;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171541/how-do-i-obtain-a-list-of-the-application-domains-my-application-has-created