# ContentControl inside ListBox going outside ListBox when scrolled

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, contentcontrol

I currently have a `ListBox` that has a `DataTemplate` (for a custom class) that is a `TabControl` (bound to a list of charts) that contains a `ContentControl` (to show the chart).

When I scroll the ListBox, the tabs of the TabControl goes off the screen correctly. However the chart of the ContentControl within the TabControl goes out of the ListBox and over other elements.

Code Sample:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ChartItemsList}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
<ListBox.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type m:ChartItemsWrapper}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <shared:PixelSnapper>
                <TabControl Background="White" BorderBrush="DarkGray" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="3,0" Padding="0" TabStripPlacement="Right">
                    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                                <Border BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0">
                                    <Grid Background="White">
                                        <Stuff>
                                        <Grid Margin="0,25,0,0">
                                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Chart}" Visibility="Collapsed" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="mainChart"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </DockPanel>
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers ... />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <TabControl.ItemTemplate ... />
                    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle ... />
                </TabControl>
            </shared:PixelSnapper>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.Resources>
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight" IsItemsHost="True"  Orientation="Horizontal"></WrapPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

I tried setting ZIndexes, changing the binding, but it just seems that ListBoxes and ContentControls don't mix. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry this is not going to be the answer most people in the future will find useful but in my particular case the binding of `<ContentControl Content="{Binding Chart}" .../>` was pointing to a chart that can only be displayed within a WinFormHost.

Since WinForms and WPF are different rendering technologies, and WinForms UI elements will always be overlaid over WPF ones which is causing my WinForm charts to go outside the ListBox when they were supposed to be scrolled "off screen."

For more on this, refer to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9584166/cant-see-wpf-control-on-top-winform-control) or [this MSDN post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dwayneneed/2013/02/26/mitigating-airspace-issues-in-wpf-applications/). A note, in my research, some people were saying this problem was fixed in the .NET 4.5 release but it seems that it was not due to complications and had to be dropped from the release (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535167/has-airspace-support-definitely-been-dropped-in-wpf-4-5)).

Answer (score 0):

Add `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` to your ListBox.
I had similar issue before and this fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Other than `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` suggested by vishakh369, you  can also try `ClipToBounds="True"`. Not sure what are the differences though, maybe you can try it out to see which one does it better.