# wpf interface element is covered by ocx control

Tags: c#, wpf, ocx

I use WPF to call the C++ encapsulated ocx control to display on the interface, but the WPF native control cannot be displayed on the ocx component. Here is my code to display the ocx control:

```
<WindowsFormsHost Name="host"  Width="640" Height="470" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <ocx:AxWipFaceOCX x:Name="axWipFaceOCX1"></ocx:AxWipFaceOCX>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

Comment: From my experience: If you have _any_ chance to get rid of that ocx: do it. Meanwhile: Can you add a screenshot (or sketch if you cannot give away sensitive data) of what it looks like and sketch what it _should_ look like?

Comment: Check this, might be same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978917/render-wpf-control-on-top-of-windowsformshost

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Render WPF control on top of WindowsFormsHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978917/render-wpf-control-on-top-of-windowsformshost)

Comment: No, it ’s a bit bad to create another window to cover. What I want to ask is to display wpf control on WindowsFormsHost in the same window