# Hosting CaptureElement with WindowsXamlHost Overlay

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, uwp, xaml-islands

Im trying to overlay a `Grid` on top of `CaptureElement` (Camera Feed) hosted with `WindowsXamlHost` in my WPF .NET Core 3.1 App, but the `CaptureElement` always stays on top of any other control.

Is it not possible to overlay a grid on top of `WindowsXamlHost/CaptureElement`?

Î have created a Sample Application https://github.com/ValonK/SampleWPFXamlHost. I need the `CaptureElement` and haven't found anything to capture camera feed and put some overlays above them.

Xaml Code

```
<Window x:Class="SampleWPFXamlHost.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SampleWPFXamlHost"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid Height="200"
              Width="200"
              Background="Red"/>
        <ContentControl HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                        Content="{Binding XamlHostCaptureElement}"/>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel : PropertyChangedAware
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        GetUwpCaptureElement();
    }

    private MediaCapture _mediaCapture;

    public MediaCapture MediaCapture {
        get {
            if (_mediaCapture == null)
                _mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
            return _mediaCapture;
        }
        set {
            _mediaCapture = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MediaCapture));
        }
    }


    public CaptureElement CaptureElement { get; set; }

    public WindowsXamlHost XamlHostCaptureElement { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create / Host UWP CaptureElement
    /// </summary>
    private void GetUwpCaptureElement()
    {
        XamlHostCaptureElement = new WindowsXamlHost
        {
            InitialTypeName = "Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.CaptureElement"
        };
        XamlHostCaptureElement.ChildChanged += XamlHost_ChildChangedAsync;
    }

    private async void XamlHost_ChildChangedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var windowsXamlHost = (WindowsXamlHost)sender;

        var captureElement = (CaptureElement)windowsXamlHost.Child;
        CaptureElement = captureElement;
        CaptureElement.Stretch = Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Stretch.UniformToFill;

        try
        {
            await StartPreviewAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    private async Task StartPreviewAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await MediaCapture.InitializeAsync();
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            //_logger.Info($"The app was denied access to the camera \n {ex}");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            CaptureElement.Source = MediaCapture;
            await MediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
        }
        catch (System.IO.FileLoadException ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
}

public class PropertyChangedAware : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it not possible to overlay a grid on top of WindowsXamlHost/CaptureElement?

No. Just like a Windows Forms control in a `WindowsFormsHost`, a `WindowsXamlHost` is hosted in a separate HWND that is always drawn on top of the WPF elements.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/wpf-and-windows-forms-interoperation):

> A hosted Windows Forms control is drawn in a separate HWND, so it is always drawn on top of WPF elements.

There is a similar question with some answers available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978917/render-wpf-control-on-top-of-windowsformshost).

Answer (score 1):

I came across this same issue when I was trying to host a `CaptureElement` inside of my WPF app using XAML Islands.  As mm8 said, the issue is because WPF will draw the WindowsXamlHost after any of the WPF elements.

But there is a quick solution for this problem if you are simply trying to overlay things like a `TextBlock` over your `CaptureElement`.  Just host a UWP user control instead of hosting the `CaptureElement` directly.  Using MVVM, you can pass the text from your WPF app to your UWP user control and it will display.

Example:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyUwpApp.MyUserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">

    <Grid>
        <CaptureElement x:Name="captureElement"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}" Foreground="Yellow" FontSize="64" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```